# How to use different runners for a specific value in matrix strategy

Tags: github-actions

Is there a way to use a higher resource runner machine for a specific value in matrix strategy?

this is a sample GitHub action:

```
  test-app:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 60
    strategy:
        matrix: 
          run: ['app1', 'app2', 'app3']
```

for `app3` I need 2x resources on the runner machine. Could someone please help me? I searched a lot but could find the answer here on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

You need two changes to make this happen:

1. Define an object to reference your `runs-on` values
2. Reference those in the job definition

I have only been able to do this by referencing outputs from a previous job:

```yaml
jobs:
  test-setup:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      runners: '{"app1":"ubuntu-latest", "app2": "ubuntu-latest", "app3": "ubuntu-22.04-16core"}'
    steps:
      - run: echo no-op
  test-app:
    needs: [test-setup]
    runs-on: ${{ fromJSON(needs.test-setup.outputs.runners)[matrix.run] }}
    timeout-minutes: 60
    strategy:
        matrix: 
          run: ['app1', 'app2', 'app3'] 
    steps:
      - run: echo ${{ matrix.run }}
```

This is the `runs-on` value: `${{ fromJSON(needs.test-setup.outputs.runners)[matrix.run] }}`, it just pulls the string from the previous job's output

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as using an expression based on the matrix values, e.g.

```
runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
strategy:
  matrix:
    os: [ubuntu-20.04, ubuntu-22.04]
```

Here we directly use matrix.os variable, but instead you can use any complex expression.